# Transitioning Text in D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to add text to nodes that are created dynamically, specifically, like this graph:
http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/999346

I am NOT looking to add text to collapsible graphs, but to add text to graphs that insert nodes at runtime, as shown in the above example.

So far I have the following additional code:

```
node.enter().append("text", "g")
        .attr("x", function(d) { return (d.x);})
        .attr("y", function(d) { return (d.y);})
        .text(function(d) { return d.name; })
        .attr("text-anchor", function(d) { return d.children || d._children ? "end" : "start"; });
```

This adds text but it doesn't move when nodes are inserted.

The below lines appear to move the nodes and links in the example:

```
    var t = svg.transition()
            .duration(duration);

    t.selectAll(".link")
            .attr("d", diagonal);

    t.selectAll(".node")
            .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.px = d.x; })
            .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.py = d.y; });
```

but adding a similar function for text:

```
 t.selectAll(".text")
        .style("fill-opacity", 1);
```

has no effect.

I would very much appreciate any guidance on this matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The nodes are all identified with `d3.selectAll('.node')`, so you need to give them the node class.

Also, the `cx` and `cy` attributes don't exist on text elements. you want `x` and `y` instead.

Example fiddle is [here.](http://jsfiddle.net/X43X5/)